HTML video tag with absolute links
I am learning HTML, but I am having issue with using video tag. I do it well with relative links-
<video src="shoonSHAN.mp4"controls height="255"></video>
But when using with absolute links, I am having problems. For example  take this code-
<video src="https://youtu.be/W0DM5lcj6mw?si=zcSf5TSQzuxkHcFl" controls height="225"></video>
Here is how I am seeing it in Chrome-
ERROR PREVIEW
I tried clicking on it, but no success came.
I tried searching of this on internet, I expected that this might be a common error and someone on the internet must be giving solution, but I founded nothing.

the reason of your error is not because absolute links, it's because your absolute links doesn't return a video file but rather a webpage, you should consider replacing that links with ones that directly return a video resource (look for any video links online and you can see that it will works with absolute link)
but if you want to attach youtube video into a html file, you should use an iframe provided by youtube (click share and select embed options)
